# Why I cannot use expected in JUnit 4

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Im trying to test method responsible for retreiving data from file.
I want to test if exception is thrown properly.

```
   package contentfile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ContentFileRetrieverService implements ContentFileRetriever {

    @Override
    public String[] getContentFile(String pathName) {

        Stream<String> contentFileStream;
        try {
            contentFileStream = Files.lines(Paths.get(pathName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }

        return contentFileStream.toArray(String[]::new);
    }
}
```

My tests:

```
package contentfile;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

class ContentFileRetrieverServiceTest {

    private ContentFileRetrieverService contentFileRetrieverService = new ContentFileRetrieverService();

    @Test
    void getContentFile() {
        String pathFile = "src\\test\\java\\resources\\TestText.txt";
        String[] testedContent = contentFileRetrieverService.getContentFile(pathFile);
        String[] expected = {"Line1 a", "Line2 b c", "Line 3"};
        assertArrayEquals(expected, testedContent);
    }

    @Test(expected =  IllegalArgumentException.class)
    void getContentFileWhenFileDoesNotExist() {
        String pathFile = "unknown";
        String[] testedContent = contentFileRetrieverService.getContentFile(pathFile);
    }
}
```

pom,xml

```
<dependency>

    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

It wont compile as it cannot resolve method `excepted` what I am making wrong?
PS:
Could you tell me if I test this method properly with these two methods?

Comment: The attribute is named ["expected"](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html#expected()); you misspelled it.

Comment: @rgettman Sorry, it should be expected. I rewrite it and make this mistake right now. It still does not work even if I write `@Test(expected  =  IllegalArgumentException.class)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're mixing JUnit 4 and JUnit 5.

The `expected` element exists in the JUnit4 [`@Test`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Test.html)

JUnit 5 offers more powerful [`assertThrows`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows(java.lang.Class,org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable)) instead

Comment: But I have dependency for `<version>4.12</version>` so how am I mixing with JUnit 5?

Comment: Probably you have not only this dependency. Maybe your IDE supplies one... Your test class imports `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` which is from JUnit5 and `org.junit.Assert` which is from JUnit 4. Try to look for dependencies on `org.junit.jupiter` group artifacts

Comment: I added edit and pasted pom.xml with versions. Could you check it out?

Comment: Yes the `junit-jupiter-api` is the dependency on JUnit5. So you can either remove dependency on JUnit4 and embrace `Assertions.assertThrows`... Or stick with JUnit4 and use `org.junit.Test` instead of `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`